# How do I select which expansion to play?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-iv

I downloaded and installed both the Lost and Gay Tony expansions. When I started GTA4 it asked me if I wanted to play Gay Tony, I said no, and Lost loaded. Now it doesn't ask me anymore, it just loads Lost.

How can I play Gay Tony or the Original game now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the game is automatically loading your most recent save, which is for `The Lost and Damned`.

Have you tried starting a new game?